# Segmentaton Fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I was trying to work on a CodeChef problem (Problem Link :: http://www.codechef.com/problems/K2). The code should take in a input for each test case, process, display the result, before moving to the next testcase. But it is just taking inputs without any output.
I am unable to figure out the error as the g++ compiler isn't giving any.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using std::string;

char baseArr[]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};

bool isPalin(string number)
{
    int len=number.size();
    bool flag=true;
    for(int i=0; i<len/2, flag==true; i++)
    {
        if(number[i]==number[len-(i+1)])
            continue;
        else
        {
            flag=false;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
string baseChange(long int number, int base)
{
    int i=1;
    int rem=0;
    string output =" ";
    while(number>0)
    {
        rem=number%base;
        number=number/base;
        output=baseArr[rem]+output;
    }
    return output;
}
int main()
{
    long int input;
    int testcase;
    string number;
    int i;
    bool palin=false;
    scanf("%d", &testcase);
    while(testcase--)
    {
        palin=false;
        scanf("%ld", &input);
        for(i=2; palin==false;i++)
            {
                {
                    palin=isPalin(baseChange(input, i));
                }
            }
        printf("%d\n",i);

    }
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Why not just step through the code in your debugger until you find the bug ?

Comment: @Shamim Hafiz - There is no error. "But it is just taking inputs without any output."  It's just not behaving as desired.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz : The compiler is not showing any error. But when I run the prog, it just keeps on taking input.

Comment: @PaulR - I am new to programming, and don't really know how to use a debugger though am trying to learn. I have tried testing by printing some random statements, and anything after `scanf("%ld", &input);` is not getting executed.

Comment: Adding printf statements can be a useful way to debug, but now would be a good time to learn to use a debugger properly - it will save you a lot of time and effort in the long run.

Comment: the i<len/2 in your for loop has no effect...

Comment: @ArneKjetilAndersen : Yeah it has. It checks the elements of the string till len/2. In case it finds a difference before len/2 pos, it doesn't need to check further and hence it turns the flag off.

Comment: @PaulR : Yes, I do need to learn how to use a debugger. Will try to do that asap. :)

Comment: You are taking a very convoluted approach to that problem.  When you simplify your code, you will find it is much easier to debug.

Comment: What's with the zero initialization of variables

Comment: @Claudiordgz: Sorry, I didn't understand you.

Comment: @PsyCoder flag==true is the only thing evaluated in the for loop. If you want to evaluate both you need to use the logical AND (&&) operator... as in i<len/2 && flag == true.

Comment: @PsyCoder I need to input variables to run your code. To input variables I need to understand your code, so I read it. Then I deduce it is a palindrome finder, then I find the correct input, then I input some variables, the algorithm takes a lot of time. 

What I'm saying is that you should provide a complete test case, so we can copy paste it instead of having to deduce anything, thus maximizing the help. A SegFault is accessing a memory that has nothing allocated. The error should be obvious, but the test case you provided is incomplete.

Comment: @Claudiordgz : Oh sorry. For the test case part
Input : 1 21
Output : 2

Answer (score 2):

You assume that the maximum base will be 16, but this may not be the case. You are probably getting a segmentation fault for accessing `baseArr` beyond valid index. I have not thought of the solution, but I believe the actualy solution can be implemented without considering any character value for the digits.

Comment: But won't that depend on the input. If I provide an input such as 21, which turns out to be a palindrome in base 2, it won't have to access the array elements other than 0 and 1.

Comment: Sometimes, segmentation faults do not cause immediate crash, instead it may result in side effects such as the one described here.

Comment: @psyc0der If your code is failing to produce output for the case you describe, perhaps there are other issues than what I have described. In any case, what I have suggested is something you should look into anyway, if you want to eventually have the solution accepted.

Comment: The most straight-forward way of implementing the base changes without using a hard-coded array is to use `itoa` (or `_itoa` or `_itoa_s`).  Sadly, the C++ replacements for those functions removed one of its useful abilities:  the ability to convert to a different base.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to the Palindrome problem:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>

bool test_palindrome(const std::string& value)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < value.length() / 2; i++)
    {
        if (value[i] != value[value.length() - 1 - i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

std::string find_palindrome(unsigned long num)
{
    std::string ret = "";
    for (int i = 2; i <= 32; i++)
    {
        char buffer[100] = {0};
        std::string value = ::itoa(num, buffer, i);
        std::cout << "Testing:  Base=" << i << " Value=" << value << std::endl;
        bool test = test_palindrome(value);
        if (test)
        {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << value << " (base " << i << ")";
            ret = ss.str();
            break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long input = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter number to search:  ";
    std::cin >> input;

    std::string palin = find_palindrome(input);

    std::cout << std::endl << "Palindrome Found:  " << palin << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```